# HOw to show woocommerc products in list view?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[Exactly like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnQqX.png)

How to show woocommerce products in list view with the dimension showing in the image above, and also how to dit the product category page. Please anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the WooCommerce template files for this one. I assume the D1, L etc. fields are custom fields. [Check this custom fields generator.](https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/) I prefer the modifications with hooks and actions. Here is a good starting point for the modification with hooks: [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/) Remove actions what you don't need, and add new outputs from your custom fields to it. When you have all the fields you want to display, format the design with css (see CSS flex for this one). The process is the same at the Category pages. If you are not familiar with programming and WP, Woo template structure, you should study these topics at first.